# Remote nginx proxy server - unable to download file from website?

Tags: php, nginx, joomla, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've set up a remote reverse proxy server using nginx that is helping with traffic throttling to our website (lots of DDOS attacks lately). The website is currently built on an old version of Joomla.

When you try to download a file from the website, it redirects home rather than pushing the file download as it should.

an example link would be:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=4753
```

My nginx config is as follows

```
# Initialize Rate Limiting
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=1r/s;

    # Do Proxy Cache
    proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:10m loader_threshold=300 loader_files=200 max_size=200m;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name www.domain.com;
            return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            proxy_cache one;
            server_name domain.com;
            access_log /var/www/proxy/log/nginx.access.log;
            error_log /var/www/proxy/log/nginx_error.log debug;

            location / {
                    # apply rate limiting
                    limit_req zone=login burst=5;

                    resolver        127.0.0.1;
                    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
                    proxy_pass      http://$host$uri;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). If you will have any [tag:joomla]-related questions in the future, I recommend asking them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue.... The proxy was stripping all the request/get variables from the request. Note the changes under the "location" directive

From

```
proxy_pass      http://$host$uri;
```

To

```
proxy_pass      http://$host$request_uri;
```